# Why is only 127.0.0.1 considered as a loopback when anything from 127.0.0.0/8 is routed to localhost?

Tags: networking

In every network tutorial/reference that I've seen is as a loopback considered only 127.0.0.1 IP address. I've tried to ping any random address from 127.0.0.0/8 and it also routed me to localhost. Are there any further special IPs from 127.0.0.0/8 range?

Comment: just follow the link: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735#page-6 . This is official standard. Have you even tried to google before typing question? This case, googling is way faster!

Comment: It is not true that on all OS's, that the name "localhost" is tied to 127/8. on most linux systems, only 127.0.0.1 can be resolved to `localhost`. all other addrs in the range will loop back, but they can be assigned differant names locally. for instance debian systems tie 127.0.0.1 to "localhost" and create a name mirroring $hostname at 127.0.1.1.

Comment: As mentioned, 127.0.0.1 is not the only loopback IP address; the system keeps track of *separate* loopback addresses throughout a range. This can be handy, as when I wanted to run multiple *local* servers on one PC. *localhost* may be defined in the *hosts* file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple, it's because it is the loopback interface range of networking and default behaviour is often to just "loop back" to the host which you are on, go [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) to read a more in depth explanation.

In general there is a lot of different IP scopes reserved for a lot of different things, you can for example read about private networks [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).

Comment: I know about special addreses (multicast, private/public network etc.) I am curious why is as loopback "always" mentioned 127.0.0.1 and not whole 127.0.0.0/8

Comment: Well as mentioned in the first link I put there, the entire 127.0.0.0/8 network is designated to loopback addresses, this means that per default if nothing else is set, it will designate itself.